Count number of characters in each row and drop if all are below a certain number
I have a dataframe with many columns, all of which contain text data mixed with NaNs.
I want to count the number of characters in each cell in each column and then drop any rows where all the columns have less than 5 characters (if any cells have more than 5 characters, then the row is not dropped).
I was considering making a new column with str.len for each column and then filter out rows using that, but it seems very cumbersome.
Example:
>>> df
   column_1    column_2    column_3
0   werhi      dsfhjk       dh      ---> not filtered because some columns have more than 5 characters
1   sgds        fuo         g       ---> filtered
2   wqyuio      dsklh       fhkjfj
3   fhi         d           fgho    ---> filtered
4   sadfhkj     sdjfkhs     yyisdk

>>> df_filtered
   column_1    column_2    column_3
0   werhio      dsfhjk      dh
2   wqyuio      dsfjklh     fhkjfj
4   sadfhkj     sdjfkhs     yyisdk


Do you want all columns to have less than 100 or the sum or all columns to be less than 100?

@mozway I just edited to change the 100 to 5 since the example uses 5 and the number isn't that important.

@wjandrea I wondered the same but 5 would exclude the first row

@mozway all the columns need to have less than X characters in order for it to be filtered

Per @DrakeMurdoch's edit, at least one column needs to have len(x)>=5. I understand now. This was difficult to interpret as originally asked.

Thanks for clarifying. I updated the answer. You want OPTION 2.

No need to create new columns.
OPTION 1: minimal total string length per row
just apply to all columns, aggregate the total sum and create a boolean Series for boolean indexing:
thresh = 10
out = df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).sum(axis=1).ge(thresh)]

Output:
  column_1 column_2 column_3
0   werhio   dsfhjk       dh
2   wqyuio  dsfjklh   fhkjfj
4  sadfhkj  sdjfkhs   yyisdk

OPTION 2: minimal string length for any strings in a row
If you want to ensure all values in a column have at least a given size, compare to the threshold before aggregating with any:
thresh = 5
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).ge(thresh).any(axis=1)]

Output:
  column_1 column_2 column_3
0   werhio   dsfhjk       dh
2   wqyuio  dsfjklh   fhkjfj
4  sadfhkj  sdjfkhs   yyisdk

Intermediates
OPTION 1:
# df.apply(lambda x: x.str.len())
   column_1  column_2  column_3
0         6         6         2
1         4         3         1
2         6         7         6
3         3         1         4
4         7         7         6

# df.apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).sum(axis=1)
0    14
1     8
2    19
3     8
4    20
dtype: int64

# df.apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).sum(axis=1).ge(thresh)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

OPTION 2:
# df.apply(lambda x: x.str.len().ge(5))
   column_1  column_2  column_3
0      True      True     False
1     False     False     False
2      True      True      True
3     False     False     False
4      True      True      True

# df.apply(lambda x: x.str.len().ge(5)).any(axis=1)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool


This looks filters based on the sum of characters in each row, but not the individual cells. How would I change it to that?

Minor improvement: you can move .ge(thresh) outside the .apply().

@DrakeMurdoch As the question was not fully clear to me I provided two approaches, one for the total length and one for a minimal length per cell

@wjandrea you're right, as long as it's before any/all. This should be faster. Thanks!

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'col1': ['abc', 'de', 'fghi', 'jklmn'],
    'col2': ['opq', 'r', 'stuv', 'wx'],
    'col3': ['y', 'z', '123', '45678']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

threshold = 3

# If you want the sum of all values in a row to exceed a threshold:
row_filter = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.len()).sum(axis=1) >= threshold

# If you want the minimum value of each cell in a row to exceed a threshold
row_filter = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.len()).min(axis=1) >= threshold

filtered_df = df[row_filter]


df.apply(lambda col: col.str.len()) will create a new DF where each cell represents the length of the same cell in the original DF
sum(axis=1) will sum the length of all string in the row
>= threshold will filter out rows that are less than the desired length
filtered_df = df[row_filter] will filter the original data frame to exclude rows that don't match your predicate


A detail but you still have applymap in your text. You could also have kept applymap(len) using a fillna("") before.
